# Multiple express middleware calls

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm developing an app using express and I created a function that sets a language cookie:

```
[..]
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.cookies.lang === undefined){
      console.log(req.cookies);
    }
    next();
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
[..]
```

Everything works great but using nodemon I noticed that that function is called multiple times when I make a request and I don't know if it is a wanted behavior or if I'm making some mistakes.

This is the console log:

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
Connected to database
{ 'connect.sid': 's:NeNC-uUnHtrdlqkSI7GkbMQ6IAhwo2It.tD8Ei9k6XtPn2/4Da2AVJIjoRlK4zkWiltsdgL58Dak' }
GET /signup 304 516.356 ms - -
{ 'connect.sid': 's:id5VQwMWKzVC5ycpR6brH5YQQpbEe9Au.brQxxrNtniBmYL1swH2WRApDSyBLJk4qlEc4+8oQ9T4' }
{ 'connect.sid': 's:id5VQwMWKzVC5ycpR6brH5YQQpbEe9Au.brQxxrNtniBmYL1swH2WRApDSyBLJk4qlEc4+8oQ9T4' }
GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 304 3.662 ms - -
{ 'connect.sid': 's:id5VQwMWKzVC5ycpR6brH5YQQpbEe9Au.brQxxrNtniBmYL1swH2WRApDSyBLJk4qlEc4+8oQ9T4' }
GET /css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css 304 5.445 ms - -
{ 'connect.sid': 's:id5VQwMWKzVC5ycpR6brH5YQQpbEe9Au.brQxxrNtniBmYL1swH2WRApDSyBLJk4qlEc4+8oQ9T4' }
{ 'connect.sid': 's:id5VQwMWKzVC5ycpR6brH5YQQpbEe9Au.brQxxrNtniBmYL1swH2WRApDSyBLJk4qlEc4+8oQ9T4' }
GET /css/tooltipster-sideTip-light.min.css 304 9.551 ms - -
GET /css/app.min.css 304 8.440 ms - -
{ 'connect.sid': 's:id5VQwMWKzVC5ycpR6brH5YQQpbEe9Au.brQxxrNtniBmYL1swH2WRApDSyBLJk4qlEc4+8oQ9T4' }
GET /js/vendor/tooltipster.bundle.min.js 304 7.714 ms - -
GET /js/app.js 304 2.261 ms - -
```

Can someone enlight me? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - it looks like there are 7 logs and 7 requests which makes me think that there's a race condition between when the route is logged and when `req.cookies` is logged. I think you're ok.

Comment: A logger "feature" uh?

Comment: I believe so :) That's my best guess anyhow since the numbers match up

Comment: Yeah, maybe. At least moving it under express session solved the problem :D